# Is it possible to recover all the uncommitted files and non versioned files along with the deleted project in git repository?

Tags: git

Currently, I am doing a java project. I am creating a work space in my computer and I have cloned the projects from git repository in server.

Accidently, one of my project was deleted from the work space. It had contained

a.  some non-committed files
b.  and some un-versioned files.

While cloning the same project from server repository again, those uncommitted and unversioned files are not there. so, I am in big trouble.

Is it possible to get all the non committed and non versioned files which were present in the deleted project from work space? Please answer me as soon as possible.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Had the files been in place long enough that your system backups saved copies off elsewhere? You do back up your system(s), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No

Untracked files - are not tracked. Git knows nothing about them.

### Preventing re-occurrence

To avoid this kind of problem occurring in the future:

- Use feature branches
- Commit often (small atomic commits)
- Use `git stash`

Using branches as intended (a new branch for whatever you're working on) gives you the freedom to be able to commit whatever you like knowing that you can then use - or *not* use - these commits later.

Comment: Thank you very much for  your valueable reply. Untracked files can not be recovered it's okey. What about the tracked files but not committed after changes in the above case?

Comment: If they were not committed or they were  `git stash`ed but the `.git` folder was deleted - again: no it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No. git can't help you with files it doesn't know.

Answer (score 0):

No. if the files are untracked then git knows nothing about them.. next time look into using a feature branch and doing commits very often

```
git checkout -b <f-branch>
git commit -a
```